# Using Letters to denote coordinate points and intervals

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

On a graph with certain points denoted by letters, can you refer to intervals of the domain (let's say where the graph is increasing) using letters? For example, let's say $A (-1,-1)$ and $B (2,3)$ is an interval where the graph is increasing. Can I say, $(A,B)$ is the interval of increase?

Comment: Is $A$ an *interval* or a *point*?

Comment: Is the domain something other than a connected subset of the real axis? If not, it is hard to understand why you'd need four numbers to describe two points on the x-axis. If so, you need to do more work explaining the context you're working in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean that $A(-1,-1)$ and $B(2,3)$ are points on the graph of a function (call it $f$).

Technically one should say that the function is increasing **on the interval** $[x_A,x_B]\equiv[-1,2]$ between the *domain* values $x_A=-1$ and $x_B=2$ (this interval is the projection of the indicated portion of the graph down onto the $x$-axis).

The thing that is increasing is the associated value $y=f(x)$ as $x$ varies through that interval: $f(x)$ increases from $y_A=f(-1)=-1$ to $y_B=f(2)=3$.

The reason is that you have to be comparing real numbers, not points, to say that they are increasing. Points don't increase, because there is not a natural order for points. You can't say $B>A$, for example; but you *can* say $3>-1$. So you let one variable change ($x$), and observe the behavior of the other variable ($y$) to see if it is increasing, decreasing, etc. Since the relationship between $x$ and $y$ is $f$ (because $y=f(x)$), we then say (perhaps sloppily) that "$f$ is increasing on the domain interval $[-1,2]$".

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are saying, then what you want to express can simply be said by saying that $(-1,2)$ (the *interval, not the point*) is the interval of increase.

Answer (score 1):

You better say, that in $[-1,2]$ the graph of the function is increasing. The letters $A$ and $B$ denote points on the *graph* of the function and not on the *domain* of the function. Knowing this, both following formulations sound correct to me:

- the graph of the function is increasing between points $A$ and $B$, or
- the graph of the function is increasing when the input variable (ok, a too formal term for $x$) is between $-1$ and $2$.

Answer (score 0):

depends on what your instructor wants. if you can make (A,B) well defined, then it should be okay. personally, I would do it.

Comment: My instructor is slightly confused on the issue. She initially agreed with me but another student said that because the letter represents an XY pair... it just doesn't work? I think it makes sense, honestly.

Comment: @TSwift The problem is that the word **interval** is reserved for subsets of $\mathbb R$ (specifically, subsets of the type $\{x\in\mathbb R|a<x<b\}$), so it would be fair to either say the function is increasing on $(-1,2)$ or that the function increases *from* $A$ to $B$.